# Enable and disable buttons dynamically on window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to update a custom message box I made (Inherited from Window)

The solution im trying to find is to show the messagebox with the buttons disabled, until a condition changes, then enable them again to allow the program to continue.

Ive tried using the "show" method instead of show dialogue, but then the context does not get displayed.

Please see below for my current approach:

```
TPromptWindow w_continue;
bool b_enableBtn = false;

do {
w_continue = new TPromptWindow("Please Wait", "OK", "Cancel", b_enableBtn);
w_continue.ShowDialog();
} 
while ( conditionBoolean );
w_continue.Close(); // I know this doesnt work, but just tryign to show my intentions

b_enableBtn = true;
w_continue = new TPromptWindow("Please Wait", "OK", "Cancel", b_enableBtn);
w_continue.ShowDialog();
```

The first problem with my solution is that the first message shown will not self destroy, it always waits on the user input. I tried calling "Close" after the do while statement but that wouldn't close down the first dialogue to show the next one with buttons enabled.

Can anyone give me any guidance please?

Comment: ShowDialog will block the current thread.

Comment: Your current "solution" is just wrong. Try using a viewmodel approach instead, where you set the DataContext of the Window and then create bindings in the view to a boolean value "IsEnabled" in the viewmodel, then the view will get updated when the value changes.

Comment: Basically you should just disable the methods. And whenever it should be enabled, Invoke it and enable everything.

Comment: I wish I could just disabel the methods, the the booleanCondition is based on USB changes, I have tried my best to extract the problem in a simple form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dialog will stop the code from working until you confirm it. 
I think for what you want to do, you need to start a thread, block the current input with the dialog and when the thread with "the work to do" has finished close the dialog or continue.

With the code you wrote, you can not exit the do while loop.

Try looking at this: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx

I have a program where I do something in the background and I display that the user should wait with a progressdialog. You could replace this progressdialog with any other dialog you want. You just need to create a form and make it modal so it blocks the input. This is done with the locked attribute. 
So here is an example how i do it:

```
//This is a bool to see if some other process is already running.
if (isProcessRunning)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Currently someone else is working!!!");
     return;
}`var progressDialog = new ProgressDialog();
    //if you don't have a maximum value because you don't know how long it will take you should set indeterminate to true.
    progressDialog.setMaximum(<maximum value>);
    progressDialog.Text = "<what are you doing>";
    var backgroundThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                isProcessRunning = true;
                //this does not have to be a loop, you can also do other stuff you just have to set you bar to indeterminate then.
                foreach (<do my stuff>)
                {
                    <do stuff here that takes time>
                    progressDialog.IncrementProgress();
                }

                //Close the progressdialog threadsave.
                if (progressDialog.InvokeRequired)
                    progressDialog.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => progressDialog.Close()));

                isProcessRunning = false;
            });

        backgroundThread.Start();
        progressDialog.ShowDialog();
```

This should solve your problem. If you need the progressdialog. 
Don't forget that when you access your dialog you need to take care that it is threadsave. For example to increment the progress you do it like that:

```
public void IncrementProgress()
    {
        if (progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            progressBar1.BeginInvoke(
                new Action(() =>
                {
                    progressBar1.Value++;
                }
                    ));
        }
        else
        {
            progressBar1.Value++;
        }
    }
```

I hope I could help you with that.

Comment: This sounds perfect, ill have alook into that, thanks, ill get back soon once I try this out

Comment: Ive tried implementing a thread to block* the input, but I cant seem to prevent the dialogue input still, would you have an example source that shows this?